# How to apply border radius and spacing between the mat-rows?

Tags: html, angular

Here is my code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vodqhe

I'm trying to make the rows appear as shown in the picture[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin):

> [The margin property] applies to all elements except elements with
>   table display types other than table-caption, table and inline-table
>   **You basically can't add margin or padding to a table row  directly.**

How you set a border for table rows and specify a margin and padding depends on the border model (**collapse** or **separate**) you use.

**separate**

> In the separated borders model, the edges coincide with the border
>   edges of cells. (And thus, in this model, there may be gaps between
>   the rows, columns, row groups or column groups, corresponding to the
>   'border-spacing' property.)
>
> In this model, each cell has an individual border. The
>   'border-spacing' property specifies the distance between the borders
>   of adjoining cells. (...) Rows, columns, row groups, and column groups
>   cannot have borders (i.e., user agents must ignore the border
>   properties for those elements).

**collapse**

> The edges of the rows, columns, row groups and column groups in the
>   collapsing borders model coincide with the hypothetical grid lines on
>   which the borders of the cells are centered. (And thus, in this model,
>   the rows together exactly cover the table, leaving no gaps; ditto for
>   the columns.)
>
> In the collapsing border model, it is possible to specify borders that
>   surround all or part of a cell, row, row group, column, and column
>   group. (...) Also, in this model, a table does not have padding (but
>   does have margins).

as in your code border model is separate so you should use these set of css

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0 8px !important;
}

td.mat-cell {
 padding: 16px 0 16px 0;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #ffa600;
 border-top: 2px solid #ffa600;
}

td.mat-cell:first-child {
  border-left: 2px solid #ffa600;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

td.mat-cell:last-child {
  border-right: 2px solid #ffa600;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

i have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jtoldq) for you.